# Split HTML into Dictionnary/ Pandas

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup

I would like to split this HTML data and convert this into Dictionnary and after convert into Pandas object. But i didn't find a solution to split properly the string, because the name before : can be modify and my idea is use a generic solution to extract the string before and after the :
I would like to have only the string like this "Motif :" in name and the value after in reasons.

```
    {
    'name': ['Module :'], 
    'reasons': ['GA']
}
```

```html
<html><head></head> <body> <div> Motif (ajout, modif,&#8230;) :&#160;Repassage en Rebasement &quot;Holdings Computed&quot; au  lieu de  </div> <div> &quot;Holdings Computed (static)&quot; en attendant la correction MEP 15 septembre </div> <div>  </div> <div> Demandeur (Nom Pr&#233;nom) :&#160;suite &#224; pbs remont&#233;s (jusqu'&#224; 8 freezes par jour) </div> <div> Date et support de la demande :&#160;20150817 mail  </div> <div> Modifications <ul> <li> Module :&#160;GA </li> <li> Vue :&#160;toutes </li> <li> Field :&#160; </li> <li> Toolbar ou autre :&#160; </li> </ul> </div> </body></html>
```

First Solution :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

html_text = "<html>#0d0A <head>#0d0A #0d0A </head>#0d0A <body>#0d0A <div>#0d0A Motif (ajout, modif,&#8230;) :&#160;Repassage en Rebasement &quot;Holdings Computed&quot; au #0d0A lieu de #0d0A </div>#0d0A <div>#0d0A &quot;Holdings Computed (static)&quot; en attendant la correction MEP 15 septembre#0d0A </div>#0d0A <div>#0d0A #0d0A </div>#0d0A <div>#0d0A Demandeur (Nom Pr&#233;nom) :&#160;suite &#224; pbs remont&#233;s par #0d0A (jusqu'&#224; 8 freezes par jour)#0d0A </div>#0d0A <div>#0d0A Date et support de la demande :&#160;20150817 mail #0d0A </div>#0d0A <div>#0d0A Modifications#0d0A#0d0A <ul>#0d0A <li>#0d0A Module :&#160;GA#0d0A </li>#0d0A <li>#0d0A Vue :&#160;toutes#0d0A </li>#0d0A <li>#0d0A Field :&#160;#0d0A </li>#0d0A <li>#0d0A Toolbar ou autre :&#160;#0d0A </li>#0d0A </ul>#0d0A </div>#0d0A </body>#0d0A</html>#0d0A"

html_text = html_text.replace('#0d0A','')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'html.parser')
data = [[x.text for x in y.findAll('div')] for y in soup]
dict_html = defaultdict(list)

for i in list(itertools.chain(*data)):
    list_split = i.split(':')
    list_split = [i.lstrip().strip() for i in list_split]
    dict_html['name'].append(list_split[0])
    dict_html['reasons'].append(list_split[1])
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What you mentioned in the question is different from what you are doing in your code. Could you explain clearly what you need with expected Output ?

Comment: In my HTML file i have for example Module : GA and i would like to split the 'Module :'  and 'GA' but no use the name, just a generic method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is not clear, I am assuming that you wish to store the `<ul>` data in a dictionary.

This code will get the data from the `ul` and put that in a dictionary in the format you mentioned and prints it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

html_text = "<html>#0d0A <head>#0d0A #0d0A </head>#0d0A <body>#0d0A <div>#0d0A Motif (ajout, modif,&#8230;) :&#160;Repassage en Rebasement &quot;Holdings Computed&quot; au #0d0A lieu de #0d0A </div>#0d0A <div>#0d0A &quot;Holdings Computed (static)&quot; en attendant la correction MEP 15 septembre#0d0A </div>#0d0A <div>#0d0A #0d0A </div>#0d0A <div>#0d0A Demandeur (Nom Pr&#233;nom) :&#160;suite &#224; pbs remont&#233;s par #0d0A (jusqu'&#224; 8 freezes par jour)#0d0A </div>#0d0A <div>#0d0A Date et support de la demande :&#160;20150817 mail #0d0A </div>#0d0A <div>#0d0A Modifications#0d0A#0d0A <ul>#0d0A <li>#0d0A Module :&#160;GA#0d0A </li>#0d0A <li>#0d0A Vue :&#160;toutes#0d0A </li>#0d0A <li>#0d0A Field :&#160;#0d0A </li>#0d0A <li>#0d0A Toolbar ou autre :&#160;#0d0A </li>#0d0A </ul>#0d0A </div>#0d0A </body>#0d0A</html>#0d0A"

html_text = html_text.replace('#0d0A','')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text,'html.parser')


ul = soup.find('ul')
for i in ul.findAll('li'):
    d = {}
    temp = i.text.split(':')
    d['name'] = [temp[0].strip() + ' :']
    d['reason'] = [temp[1].strip()]

    print(d)
```

```
Output:

{'name': ['Module :'], 'reason': ['GA']}
{'name': ['Vue :'], 'reason': ['toutes']}
{'name': ['Field :'], 'reason': ['']}
{'name': ['Toolbar ou autre :'], 'reason': ['']}
```